# Monadic if else

Tags: haskell, monads

I am new to Haskell and want to generate an `Arbitrary` tree. 
So my first idea is to create an arbitary bool, if it is true then return an empty tree and else create a non-empty one:

```
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (BinaryTree a)
  arbitrary = do
    createNonEmpty <- arbitrary
    if createNonEmpty 
      then return Nil
      else generateNonEmptyTree
```

But this pattern of creating the bool and use it just for that if seems a bit odd and it feels like there should be a more idiomatic way. 
Is there already some kind of "monadic if" in the standard library that I could use like

```
arbitrary = ifM arbitrary (return Nil) (generateNonEmptyTree)
```

Or what else is the most idiomatic way to solve this?

Comment: `ifM` is indeed a very popular idea that exists in a number of "general-purpose" libraries, [check out Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/lts-11.2/hoogle?q=ifM).

Comment: If I understand correctly these are non standard libraries?

Comment: Unlike .NET or Java or other similar ecosystems, most Haskell libraries are "non-standard". The only "standard" one would probably be Prelude. To some degree of approximation, one could consider Stack to be the Haskell "standard", and in that sense all those libraries are, in fact, "standard", since they're included in the Stack snapshot.

Comment: @danielspaniol By standard do you mean the [libraries of the Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellpa2.html#x20-192000II)? It is *really* small. In fact `Arbitrary` is not there...

Comment: By arbitrary do you mean random?

Comment: @ThomasCook No, he means [`Arbitrary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html) from the *non-standard* QuickCheck I believe.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin (1) "Unlike .NET or Java or other similar ecosystems, most Haskell libraries are 'non-standard'" -- Indeed; standard versus non-standard libs isn't really relevant in Haskell practice. (2) "To some degree of approximation, one could consider Stack to be the Haskell 'standard', and in that sense all those libraries are, in fact, 'standard'" -- Even with the caveats, I feel this is too much of a stretch. Stackage is, by design, too large and uncohesive to be seen in that way; also, the adoption of it (and Stack) isn't sufficiently close to universal.

Comment: The `array` library is also standard, but many people use `vector` or `primitive` for their array needs instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For QuickCheck in particular, I'd use `oneof`:

```
arbitrary = oneof [return Nil, generateNonEmptyTree]
```

It does essentially what you propose in your question (generate a one-off value, then use it immediately):

```
oneof :: [Gen a] -> Gen a
oneof [] = error "QuickCheck.oneof used with empty list"
oneof gs = choose (0,length gs - 1) >>= (gs !!)
```

But since it's a library function, this means you don't have to *see* the one-off values in your own code.

Answer (score 6):

My general solution to the "use once binding" is `-XLambdaCase`:

```
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (BinaryTree a)
  arbitrary = arbitrary >>= \case
    True  -> return Nil
    False -> generateNonEmptyTree
```

Alternately, you could use something like

```
bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a
bool f _ False = f
bool _ t True = t
```

(`Bool`'s equivalent to `either` or `foldr`)

```
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (BinaryTree a)
  arbitrary = bool generateNonEmptyTree (return Nil) =<< arbitrary
```